# Mocha + Babel + React Modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, browserify, babeljs

How can I configure Mocha/Babel to also transform a module in my `node_modules` folder when required?

I am developing an application in ES6 with react.

I include an external react component which I installed through `npm install`.

When I run the test (`mocha --recursive --compilers js:babel/register`) the test fails with an `Unexpected token '<'` error from the external module.

The reason is that the external react module needs to be transformed when being loaded. This is specified in the modules `package.json` like so:

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "reactify"
  ]
}
```

It runs fine for the browser. The source is compiled with `browserify -t babelify`. The `browserify` information from the `package.json` is used and the module is transformed properly when it is loaded.

How can I configure Mocha/Babel to take this also into account?
Or how can I configure Mocha/Babel to also compile the modules in the `node_modules` folder?
Or any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Babel will, by default, not transpile the `node_modules` directory. If you wish to disable this, you can set the `ignore` option to `false`.

On the command line, you can pass `--ignore false` to either `babel` or `babel-node` to allow Babel to transpile the `node_modules` directory.

For your uses, you can pass Mocha the `--compilers js:babel/register` option to transpile the files Mocha accesses. In order to allow Babel's register hook to transpile the `node_modules` directory, you can configure Babel with a `.babelrc` file. The file should contain the following: `{ "ignore": false }`.

Either of these options should allow you to use this external module (since Babel will transpile it).

Comment: `ignore` accepts [more values than just a boolean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822593/import-a-module-from-node-modules-with-babel-but-failed).

Comment: This didn't work for me, using the .babelrc config listed above, I still get un-transpiled node_modules.