# Babel unexpected token import when running mocha tests

Tags: node.js, npm, syntax-error, mocha.js, babeljs

The solutions offered in other related questions, such as including the proper presets (es2015) in .babelrc, are already implemented in my project.

I have two projects (lets call them A and B) which both use ES6 module syntax.  In Project A, I'm importing Project B which is installed via npm and lives in the node_modules folder. When I run my test suite for Project A, I'm getting the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Which is preceded by this alleged erroneous line of code from Project B:

> (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import
>   createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';

The iife appears to be something npm or possibly babel related since my source file only contains "import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'; The unit tests in Project B's test suite runs fine, and if I remove Project B as a dependency from Project A, my test suite then (still using es6 imports for internal project modules) works just fine.

Full Stack Trace:

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/ProjectA/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:138:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (actionCreators.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at loader (/ProjectA/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:130:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/ProjectA/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:140:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/ProjectA/src/components/core/wrapper/wrapper.js:28:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at loader (/ProjectA/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:130:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/ProjectA/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:140:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/ProjectA/src/components/core/wrapper/wrapperSpec.js:15:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at loader (/ProjectA/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:130:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/ProjectA/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:140:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at /ProjectA/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:219:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/ProjectA/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:216:14)
    at Mocha.run (/ProjectA/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:468:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/ProjectA/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:403:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:430:10)
    at startup (node.js:141:18)
    at node.js:980:3
```

Here is my test command from package.json:

```
"test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register '+(test|src)/**/*Spec.js'"
```

This StackOverflow post is similar but doesn't offer a solution for my use of the command line:
[import a module from node_modules with babel but failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822593/import-a-module-from-node-modules-with-babel-but-failed)

Comment: If you are distributing a module on npm, you should only be distributing the transpiled version of that module.

Comment: This project is very light-weight.  It's intended mostly for my own use, or others if they have a transpiration process in place that can support it. I'm trying to achieve "vanilla es6" in these dependencies.

Comment: Weird, there is no option to edit my comment. transpilation*

Comment: I think you forget to configure the babel in package.json. add those to your package.json  "babel": {
    "presets": ["es2015"]
  }

Comment: Note: [according to the documentation](http://mochajs.org/#about-babel) `--compilers` is not necessary, `--require babel-register` should be used instead: "If your ES6 modules have extension .js, you can npm install --save-dev babel-register and use mocha --require babel-register; --compilers is only necessary if you need to specify a file extension."

Comment: Finally I was able to get this to work using `"babel":{"presets": ["es2015"]}` it was the last thing i was missing!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It seems the only solution is to explicitly include:

```
require('babel-core/register')({
  ignore: /node_modules/(?!ProjectB)/
});
```

in a test helper file, and pass that along to mocha in my test command:

```
mocha --require ./test/testHelper.js...
```

---

**The final solution:**

Add ***registerBabel.js***: a separate file whose job is to require babel-core/register...

```
require('babel-core/register')({
  ignore: /node_modules/(?!ProjectB)/
});
```

Add an ***entry.js*** if your application also relies on babel-node. This acts as a wrapper for your es6 containing application.

```
require('./registerBabel');
require('./server'); // this file has some es6 imports
```

You would then run your application with `node entry`

For mocha testing, ***testHelper.js*** should require registerBabel.js as well to initialize babel support at run time.

```
require('./registerBabel');
```

And run your mocha tests with `mocha --require ./testHelper.js '+(test)/**/*Spec.js'`

This will recursively test any file ending in "Spec.js" within "./test". Substitute the pattern with one matching the specs in your project.

Comment: It seems that `ignore` regex is a little off. I had to add an escaping backslash right after node_modules: `ignore: /node_modules\/(?!ProjectB)/` in order for the babelRegister file to work. Otherwise seems great!

Comment: This doesn't allow us to use Rollupify because of the require statements. Would you know of a way of doing this without using the require statements?

Comment: This is great, but what about tools that don't allow to add code like this and want to run your files directly. Then you end up with `babel-node` which doesn't allow such a thing using `.babelrc`.

Comment: This is not wrong, but the solutions below are much easier.

Comment: What If i want to ignore more than one "project"? say ProjectA and ProjectB

Something like this but can't get the syntax right 

require('babel-core/register')({
  ignore: /node_modules\/(?!ProjectA|?!ProjectB)/
});

Comment: your awesome! Babel was processing my ES6 code when just running the server, but mocha testing would fail.  Your answer solved it.  I tried --compilers in mocha.opts but that caused the import statements to fail.

Comment: @prauchfuss -- I already stated in the initial question that the solutions below *DID NOT* work for me as well as a link to a similar question proposing those same solutions. Maybe in newer versions it works as expected, but this was posted over a year and a half ago.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, but it turned out I also needed to extend my babelrc:

```
require('@babel/register')({
  extends: './.babelrc',
  ignore: [/node_modules\/(?!ProjectB)/]
});
```

Answer (score 85):

## For Babel <6

The easiest way to solve this problem is:

1. `npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev`
2. Add `.babelrc` to the root of the project with contents:

   ```
   {
    "presets": [ "es2015" ]
   }
   ```

Ensure that you are running mocha with the "--compilers js:babel-core/register" parameter.

## For Babel6/7+

1. `npm install @babel/preset-env --save-dev`
2. Add `.babelrc` to the root of the project with contents:

   ```
   {
    "presets": [ "@babel/preset-env" ]
   }
   ```

Ensure that you are running mocha with the `--compilers js:babel-register` (Babel 6) or `--compilers js:@babel/register` (Babel 7) parameter

For mocha version 7 or later, use `--require babel-register` or `--require @babel/register` respectively.

Comment: try running mocha with --require babel-register  param

Comment: @kolec This works. Even better though, create a `mocha.opts` file in the root of /test directory and add it there

Comment: Warning: `mocha.opts` doesn't always get picked up when using build tooling (`gulp`, `grunt`, etc).

Comment: All of this together still doesn't help (command-line, not mocha.opts).

Comment: If you want to use es2016, keep in mind that es2016 in Babel "Only compiles what's in ES2016 to ES2015" so you need *both* es2016 and es2015 in your presets array

Comment: Instead of adding a .babelrc file, just add to the package.json the line `"babel":{"presets": ["es2015"]}`

Comment: `--compilers` is now deprecated. Use [`--require`](https://mochajs.org/#-require-module-r-module) instead.

Comment: Also works for cases like this: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`

Answer (score 26):

Well sure you will have that issue, you are using ES6 that mocha don't know

So you are using babel but you don't use it in your test...

Few Solutions:

A. if you running with NPM use

> `"test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register test*.js"`

B. I'm using

> `"test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register **/*spec.jsx"`

C. From cli:

> mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register test*.js

You can read more at [http://www.pauleveritt.org/articles/pylyglot/es6_imports/](https://web.archive.org/web/20180317211439/http://www.pauleveritt.org/articles/pylyglot/es6_imports/)

Comment: thank you so much! I was missing the --compilers js:babel-core/register option

Comment: I was already doing this... did you even read the initial question?

Comment: @ThinkingInBits What did you end up using, how did you (if you did) resolve the issue? I'm having severe trouble here, tried most of these options

Comment: `--compilers` is deprecated now, looks like `--require` is the only option safe to go

Answer (score 23):

I ran into that same issue. Having tried every other solution on stackoverflow and beyond, adding this simple config on package.json did it for me:

```
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  }
```

All my ES6 imports worked after that.
By the way, I had this same configuration inside webpack.config.js, but apparently this was the only way to make it work for mocha testing as well.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: i had a .babelrc file spelled incorrectly, so it wasn't working initially. This solution works and is the recommended solution. Create a .babelrc file in your project and add {"presets":["es2015"]}

Answer (score 14):

I had `{"modules": false}` in my .babelrc file, like so:

```
"presets": [
    ["es2015", {"modules": false}],
    "stage-2",
    "react"
]
```

which was throwing

> Unexpected token import

Once i removed it, mocha ran successfully.

Comment: This was generated by Webpacker for Rails:
```
"presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "browsers": "> 1%",
          "uglify": true
        },
        "useBuiltIns": true
      }
    ],
    "react"
```
Once I removed the modules line, it worked for me.

Comment: This solved my problem when CircleCI was failing to run my jest unit tests and giving me the unexpected token import error. +1 !

Comment: This did it for me. Rails, Webpacker, etc... Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and fixed it by reading from the [babel documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation) for integrating Babel with Mocha :

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-register"
  }
}
```

Comment: For which version of Mocha and Babel?

Comment: My Babel versions are `6.26.0` except `"babel-preset-env": "1.6.0"` and  `"mocha": "3.5.3"`

Comment: Strange. This solved my problem and was a pure read-the-doc issue in my case.

Answer (score 7):

For anybody using Babel 7 and Mocha 4, some of the package names have changed a bit and the accepted answer is a bit out-dated. What I had to do was:

`npm install @babel/register --saveDev`

and adding `--require @babel/register` to the test line in `package.json`

`"test": "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --require @babel/polyfill --require @babel/register './test/**/*.spec.js'"`

The `@babel/polyfill` fixes some things like async/await functionality if you happen to be using those.

Hope that helps somebody :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm adding another ES6+mocha+babel config answer here, current as of June '19 (refer to dates on answer/commente). mocha has deprecated the `--compiler` flag, and the version that I'm using has that unavailable even with `--no-deprecation` flag, c.f. [this](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/compilers-deprecation)

Note that I won't include all of the relevant bits from the linked pages, because none of them got me to a clean test build based on the latest versions of mocha and babel; this answer should include the steps that got me to a successful test build.

Following the instructions here, and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38517612/275567), and [here](https://dev.to/bnorbertjs/my-nodejs-setup-mocha--chai-babel7-es6-43ei), I tried installing what appeared to be the minimum latest babel using `npm install`:

```
$ npm install --save-dev mocha
$ npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env
```

And I adjusted the mocha invocation in package.json, like so:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:@babel/register"
}
```

This led to errors:

```
× ERROR: --compilers is DEPRECATED and no longer supported.
```

As above, `--no-deprecation` didn't help, please reference the page linked above. So following the instructions from [here](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/compilers-deprecation) I adjusted package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require js:@babel/register"
}
```

And started seeing errors about locating babel modules, such as:

```
× ERROR: Cannot find module '@babel/register'
```

At this point I started installing babel packages until I could progress. I believe that the full install is something like:

```
$ npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env @babel/register @babel/core
```

The last change required was to update the mocha invocation in package.json, removing the `js:` prefix, like so:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require @babel/register"
}
```

I can't answer why this was necessary: if someone can answer this please leave a comment and I'll update my answer with better information.

The last thing that I did was create a .babelrc in the project directory, with the contents:

```
{
    "presets" : ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

I can't recall what prompted this, but I *believe* that it was because mocha continued to complain about not recognizing the `import` keyword in my test.js. As above, if someone can answer this please leave a comment and I'll update my answer with better information.

Comment: At this point I can run my mocha tests successfully. I realize that there are gaps in my knowledge here: I've written a lot of production javascript code but I'm a relative node noob. Anyone that sees this with more to add to the answer, please leave a comment and I'll improve the answer, OR leave your own better answer.

Answer (score 3):

`--compilers` is deprecated.

My simple solution:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-core
```

And in the package.json add your test script like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require babel-core/register ./test/**/*.js -r ./test-setup.js"
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me. I got a warning when using the `--compilers` flag.

> DeprecationWarning: "--compilers" will be removed in a future version
>   of Mocha; see https://git.io/vdcSr for more info

I therefore replaced it with the `--require` flag

```
"test":  "mocha --require babel-core/register --recursive"
```

Here's my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

My `package.json` dev dependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
  "mocha": "^5.2.0",
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the easiest way to do with with babel 6.X.X was to use nyc and then add in a `helper` file into the `pckage.json`

So here is what I used

**package.json**

```
{
  ....
  "scripts": {
    "test": "nyc mocha --reporter tap 'test/**/*.spec.js'"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "nyc": "^10.1.2",
    "webpack": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack-config": "^7.0.0",
    "webpack-dashboard": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "nyc": {
    "all": true,
    "include": [
      "src/**/*.js"
    ],
    "cache": true,
    "require": [
      "./test/helper/registerBabel.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

**babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015", //remove the {modules: false} it doesn't work with this
    "stage-2"
  ]
}
```

**registerBabel.js**

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-commonjs, import/unambiguous */
require('babel-register')();
```

Now you will be able to use es6 in your tests or wherever you need to. Mine are all failing ;)

Then `npm run test` which will fire off `nyc mocha --reporter tap 'test/**/*.spec.js'`

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue this morning with the following instructions

**Install NPM Modules**

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/polyfill
npm install --save-dev @babel/register
```

**package.json**:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require @babel/register --require @babel/polyfill src/DesktopApplication/Tests",
  }
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/env"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue this morning with the following instructions from the [official Using Babel instructions](https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation) for Mocha 4:

**Install NPM Modules**

```
npm install --save-dev babel-polyfill
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-env
npm install --save-dev babel-register
```

or a single command:

```
npm i -d babel-polyfill babel-preset-env babel-register
```

**package.json**:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require babel-polyfill --require babel-register"
  }
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["env"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to [specify the `extensions` option](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register#specifying-options) if you're using TypeScript:

```
require("@babel/register")({
  extensions: ['.jsx', '.js', '.ts', '.tsx']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed `mocha` and met the exact same error when I use `import` in my code. By doing the following actions, the issue was fixed.

```
npm install babel-core --save-dev
npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
npm install babel-preset-stage-0 --save-dev
```

And then add a `.babelrc` file:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015"
    ]
}
```

And then run `mocha` in this way:

```
mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.
When running tests I realized I actually wanted to stub dependent modules. It's good for unit testing and prevents babel from transforming submodules. So I used `proxyquire`, namely:

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire').noCallThru()

const myTestedModule = proxyquire('../myTestedModule', {
    'dependentModule1': { //stubbed module1 },
    'dependentModule2': { //stubbed module2 }
})
```

Comment: This is better fit as a comment.

Answer (score -3):

for a more future proof setting

```
npm install babel-preset-latest --save-dev
```

and in .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [ "latest" ]
}
```

as  opposed to...

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

and

```
{
 "presets": [ "es2015" ]
}
```

Comment: I guess this answer is practically not related to this question.. or rather, it could be added as a comment to another answer

Comment: @ 62mkv Thanks! Way to be a hawk and keep this place clean.