# mocha test results in browser- syntax error: uncaught token import

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai, babeljs

trying to run mocha tests and get results in browser. but getting uncaught token import error. 
Please help in how to compile the tests before running the tests in browser.

Comment: We need more info like config, etc... maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040978/babel-unexpected-token-import-when-running-mocha-tests ?

Comment: the tests run successfully on node command but when trying to run through runner.html, don't know how to compile them before running

Comment: What are you trying to test, client or node.js code ? What's your setup ?

Comment: Its client-side, with mocha, chai and babel. I tried adding webpack in the nodemodules but not sure how to add that in the package.json. Was reading about babel loaders. Can someone provide me running example with it