# Mocha and Import Syntax: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

Maintainer of multiple npm packages here. Been using [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) with the [require syntax](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#require) and wanting to migrate to the [import syntax](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-statements).

The error I am getting is

`Cannot find module '<project>/src/index' imported from <project>/test/index.spec.js`

### Steps to Reproduce

With the following three files

- `src/index.js`

```js
export const sum = (a, b) => a + b;
```

- `test/index.spec.js`

```js
import { sum } from '../src/index';

const expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('Testing Index', () => {
    it('Testing sum', () => {
        expect(sum(7, 13)).to.equal(20);
    });
});
```

- `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "mocha-debug",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha \"./test/**/*.spec.js\""
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "4.3.4",
    "mocha": "9.1.4"
  }
}
```

and using node `v14.18.2`, run `yarn install` and

```sh
yarn test

> `Cannot find module '<project>/src/index' imported from <project>/test/index.spec.js`
```

### Notes

I've found a [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040978/babel-unexpected-token-import-when-running-mocha-tests) that recommends using babel with `--require @babel/register`, but wasn't able to get over the error.

I've set up a test repo to make it easy to reproduce the issue

https://github.com/simlu/mocha-debug

### Question

What am I doing wrong here? How do I get the tests to run successfully?

Comment: Probably you need to add a file extension when importing the modules, e.g. `import { sum } from '../src/index.js'`.

Comment: @GOTO0 hum... I think I was staring at this way too long. I could swear I've tried this before... Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! :D Note that you could also use [subpath patterns](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/packages.html#packages_subpath_patterns) in your package.json to import files without having to add ".js" to the name (this works in Node 14 and later).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just adding the file extension in my case I was importing my mongodb model so I imported with the file extension .ts

```
var Employee = require('../models/Employee.ts')
```

Which solved the issue