# Server-side babel import translating

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

So it looks like the file I've asked it to convert is being converted correctly however the dependencies of that files remain as es6--any thoughts as to that for which I had not accounted?

Comment: not positive, have '--presets es2015,stage-2' settings wise, I guess es2015 then? and thank you! also, would you expect if babel is run one file, for all imported files linked to in the file to be transpiled as well?

Comment: how are you executing the transpile? Can we presume it's intended for running in node? Which version?

Comment: have it a setup as a build script with 'cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress && babel server/lib -d dist --presets es2015,stage-2', and node v6.5.0

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/a/31822668/4472840

Comment: ahh pardon looks like it's not actually able to understand the content of the import, i.e. unrecognized 'import' token in the one the included files if that helps (as opposed to not finding the file)

Comment: Babel doesn't transpile anything under node_modules by default, so it remains with the ES6 imports. Then at runtime, nodejs doesn't know how to parse that because it doesn't implement ES6 imports.

Comment: actually a local file I had linked to, sorry, found the local file well :) haha