# How to configure babel correctly to use lodash-es?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-node, lodash

I need to use `lodash-es` in my project, but I can't configure my babel correctly, it always reports errors like `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

**hello.js**

```
import upperCase from 'lodash-es/upperCase'

console.log(upperCase('lodash-es'));
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "demo": "babel-node hello"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash-es": "4.17.11"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ]
}
```

When run `babel-node hello`, it reports error like:

```
> /javascript-babel-node-use-lodash-es-issue-demo
> babel-node hello

/Users/freewind/workspace/javascript-babel-node-use-lodash-es-issue-demo/node_modules/lodash-es/upperCase.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import createCompounder from './_createCompounder.js';
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
```

I've also setup a small demo for this issue, you can clone and try it if you need: https://github.com/freewind-demos/javascript-babel-node-use-lodash-es-issue-demo

Comment: Probably relevant: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7566

Comment: @zerkms Thanks I just tried the solution in the list, adding `--ignore something`, but it doesn't work: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7566#issuecomment-404927017

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31822668/3563013

```
require("@babel/register")({
    ignore: [/node_modules\/(?!lodash-es)/],
});
```

Comment: The `ignore` line should be in your `babel.config.js` file (or `.babelrc`).

Answer (score -1):

`babel-node` by default ignores the `node_modules` directory. Which is a good thing, else it would be unnecessarily heavy. Packages in `node_modules` are (at the moment) expected to be in `commonjs` format. Instead of using `lodash-es` (es6 format)  you should just use `lodash` (commonjs format). It has exactly the same functionality, the only difference is the format it is written in. More information about that [here](https://auth0.com/blog/javascript-module-systems-showdown/).

So either tweak `babel-node` to unignore `node-modules/lodash-es` (not recommended!) or just install `lodash` with `npm install --save lodash` and then rewrite your import like:

```js
import upperCase from 'lodash/upperCase' // instead of lodash-es

console.log(upperCase('lodash-es'));
```