# How to use lodash-es in typescript correctly?

Tags: typescript, ts-node, lodash

I need to use `lodash-es` in my typescript project, but I can't configure it correctly, it always reports errors like `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

**hello.ts**

```
import upperCase from 'lodash-es/upperCase'

console.log('Hello ' + upperCase('typescript') + '!');
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "demo": "ts-node hello.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash-es": "4.17.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash-es": "4.17.1",
    "ts-node": "7.0.0",
    "typescript": "3.0.1"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

When run `ts-node hello.ts`, it reports error like:

```
/typescript-use-lodash-es-demo/node_modules/lodash-es/upperCase.js:1
    (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import createCompounder from './_createCompounder.js';
                                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
        at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
        at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
```

I've also setup a small demo for this issue, you can clone and try it if you need: https://github.com/freewind-demos/typescript-use-lodash-es-demo

A related question is to use lodash-es with babel: [How to configure babel correctly to use lodash-es?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52851818/how-to-configure-babel-correctly-to-use-lodash-es). Since I'm not sure they have exactly the same reason, so I asked for typescript here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ts-node` compiles `.ts` files as they are loaded.  It doesn't touch `.js` files; either they must already be in a form understood by Node.js (e.g., no ES6 `import` statements) or you must use a separate mechanism to transform them, such as the [`@babel/register` require hook](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-register) (essentially the same thing that is used by `babel-node`).  You would still need to configure `@babel/register` not to ignore `node_modules`, as described in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52853609).  The advice from the other answer to just use `lodash` instead of `lodash-es` is good.

Answer (score 20):

You can load types from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/lodash-es):

```
npm install --save-dev @types/lodash-es
```

And use it like:

```
import { camelCase } from "lodash-es"
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you should not use `lodash-es` but to use `lodash` because `lodash-es` is `esm` module while `lodash` is our formal `commonjs` module.

However if you want to use `lodash-es` in node, you should use it with `esm` instead of `@babel/register`. I found `@babel/register` very buggy even if i have added `babel-plugin-lodash` or `dynamic-import` plugin or `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs`, `@babel/polyfill`, etc ...

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this and this works for me:

```
import { upperCase } from 'lodash-es'; // works :)
import upperCase from 'lodash-es/upperCase'; // broken :(
```

[edit]

So I just restarted my application and now it's no longer working and I haven't made any configuration changes. Amazing.

[edit 2]

I found out that the problem probably lies in the `lodash-es` module not being transpiled out of the box, and you need to tell Webpack or Babel to do so. Here is a blog post providing some good insight: https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/tree-shake-lodash-with-webpack-jest-and-typescript-2734fa13b5cd. The article also covers how to fix the issue for Jest if you're using that.

If you're using NextJS, you can use https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules

```
// next.config.js
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules");

module.exports = withTM({
  transpileModules: ["lodash-es"]
});
```

Comment: Heads up, in the current version of `next-transpile-modules`, it's just `withTM(['lodash-es'])`